# Conditional confirm box on submitting a form based on form data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, forms, post

I have a form with some range input fields and I need to display a confirm box only if the user doesn't touch any of the range input fields. If they changed the values of all the range fields, only then the confirm box isn't displayed and request is processed.

The range fields returns -1 if not touched and returns their value if they were touched. What I need now is to display the confirm box only if the array with all the values contain at least one "-1". When the box is displayed, if the user clicks on Cancel, they can continue and set values for the other range fields, and if they hit Ok, an action from the controller is executed (form action) with the post data neglecting -1 values. All this is done, I only need to display the Confirmation box! Can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, but why not just add classes to the values that are changed and then when you submit form you check if that class exists anywhere.

Comment: My reaction would be to tie a custom javascript function to the form submit button that made an AJAX call back to the controller and have it review the data.  You didn't say if you're using jQuery, but I'd tie a jQuery dialog box if the form data isn't the way you want it.  I'm not fond of the standard RoR :confirm javascript alerts for confirmation boxes and you'd have more control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue by adding initial classnames to the range elements I had on the page and then when an element is initialised, I removed that classname. Then I linked an onclick function to the submit button of the form that checks if there's at least one classname that can be found and displays the confirm box accordingly.